# How to make files app to detect usb

Tags: boot, usb, disk-formatting

My USB stick is not being detected by the files app even after inserting the USB it is not being displayed in files. But other apps such as disk app is able to recognize the USB. I recently formatted the USB and wiped its contents. What can I do for the USB to become detectable again?

[image: screenshot of Disks application]

[image: screenshot of Files application]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a partition with a file system.

In Disks, with the disk selected, click the `+` button and follow the prompts.